# what about peanuts that makes them more nut like than bean like?

Tags: food-science, beans, nuts, peanuts, legumes

As we all know, peanuts are actually legumes and not nuts. But they taste and function much more like nuts. They can be cooked quickly like nuts while beans take a long time to cook.

What about their chemical makeup, etc., that is the reason for this?

Comment: peanuts are about 48% oil. That might be the difference you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a result of what you call "chemical make up."  It probably seems more nut-like because they are commonly roasted.  If you eat a raw peanut, it is certainly more bean-like.

Comment: But roasting other beans will not have the same effect?

Comment: ...bean dependent...ever have a roasted chick pea?  ...but, yeah, most beans...not roasted.

Comment: I've had spiced roasted green peas and edamame beans as well as chickpeas. I guess given the breadth of textures etc. covered by tree nuts those are fairly nut-like. But there is a difference in that the shells of peanuts aren't much like bean pods

Comment: @ChrisH...true...perhaps the shell facilitates the roasting.

Comment: I wonder to what extent the difference in the pod comes from the self-burying nature of peanuts.  Of course they are dried before sale even if not further processed.  I tried growing them a few years ago but the slugs got the plants